# Can't figure out why HTML Canvas arc fails with a parameter

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I've got a very simple HTML page with a Canvas element.

When I pass the 4th parameter of arc as `Math.PI * 2`, I get the red circle I expect, but when I try to do the same thing passing `3.1415 * 2`, I get no red circle.

I expect that in both cases I would get the same result with a red circle.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("solar-canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d", { alpha: false });

context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle = "red";


//const val = Math.PI * 2;
const val = 3.1415 * 2;
context.arc(190,150, 9, 0, val, true);




context.fill();
context.closePath();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Simple Solar System</title>
  </head>

  <body>xxx
    <canvas
      id="solar-canvas"
      width="380"
      height="300"
      style="border: 1px solid #aaaaaa"
    ></canvas>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: May be related to this bug: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1736

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `Math.PI`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are experiencing is best seen on an example:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
let end = 0

function draw() {      
  context.clearRect(0, 0, 90, 90)
  context.beginPath()
  context.arc(22, 40, 20, 0, end, true);
  context.stroke();
  
  context.beginPath()
  context.arc(65, 40, 20, 0, end);
  context.fillText(end, 10,10)
  context.stroke();
    
  end += 0.05
}

setInterval(draw, 100)
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="90" height="90"></canvas>
```

`3.1415 * 2` is close to `Math.PI * 2` but not exactly the same...
It's not failing just the arc is very small

PI `3.14159265...` could be rounded to `3.1416`
if you use that in your counterclockwise arc you will get the full circle.

---

There is some weirdness with that last parameter `counterclockwise` why with big numbers it keeps deleting the arc that might be an interesting question to look into